# Adjusting height and width of div and its contents

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the height and width of an HTML parent Div without changing the child div styles. Is there any option to adjust the div dimensions?

Example Scenario:
I have a tree that I am planning to use as a common code to create multiple trees. One small one big etc. So without changing the tree leaves and stem styles(child divs inside parent div), do we have an option to change parent div dimensions so that child divs will be automatically adjusted accordingly?

My fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/om1nv2sg/)

```
<div class="tree" style="position:absolute;left:20px;right:20px;
height:200px;width:200px;

">


    <div id="leaf1" style="height:90px;width:90px;background-color:green;border-radius:60px;position:absolute;left:40px;top:80px;"></div>
    <div id="leaf2" style="height:90px;width:90px;background-color:green;border-radius:60px;position:absolute;left:100px;top:85px;"></div>
    <div id="leaf3" style="height:90px;width:90px;background-color:green;border-radius:60px;position:absolute;left:80px;top:40px;"></div>
    <div id="stem" style="height: 150px;width: 30px;background-color: brown;position: absolute;left: 100px;top: 100px; z-index:-1;"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more. Usually, dimensions only affect the element you are targetting.

Answer (score 1):

build this using only background instead of inner divs and rely on percentage values:

```css
.tree {
  border:1px solid;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 36% 51%,green 22%,transparent 23%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 52% 37%,green 22%,transparent 23%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 64% 52%,green 22%,transparent 23%),
    linear-gradient(brown,brown) bottom/15% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.tree:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree"></div>
<div class="tree" style="width:200px;"></div>
<div class="tree" style="width:250px;"></div>
<div class="tree" style="width:50px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you cannot do it:

> Also keep the `css` code separate it is easy to manage, I have modified for you.

```css
<style>
.tree {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 300px; /* you can do it here */
  width: 300px;  /* you can do it here */
}

#leaf1 {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 80px;
}

#leaf2 {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 85px;
}

#leaf3 {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  top: 40px;
}

#stem {
  height: 150px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: brown;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="tree">Parent Div
  <div id="leaf1"></div>
  <div id="leaf2"></div>
  <div id="leaf3"></div>
  <div id="stem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tree size is still the same even if I decrease the height and width of tree class

Comment: Have to keep height and width to `auto` or `inherit`

Comment: to parent or child divs? I am trying to adjust the height and width of the parent div to change the size of the tree. I tried auto for child divs and it did not work.

Comment: the child divs has to be relative to the parent divs so when you fix height of parent you should have auto property to their child, incase it is bit complicated because you have used `left` and `right` property and when the height decreases or increases even that will fluctuate and may not looks good as you needed, Instead I suggest you to have individual parent divs and have different size trees inside.